# Mongoose validate field execute in both save and update time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using validate in mongoose schema for `unique name` now face issue while someone updates that record It won't allow the user to update because already have an entry in a database.

I've schema & code like following.

Schema

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let pTSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
          validator: function(v, cb) {  
            v = v.toLowerCase();
            PT.aggregate([  // Query for validate type should be unique if already exist than through error.
                {
                    $addFields:{
                        lowerCase: { $toLower: "$type" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match:{
                        lowerCase: v
                    }
                }
            ], function(err,docs){
                console.log(docs, v);
                cb(docs.length == 0);
            });
          },
          message: 'p already exists!'
        }
    }
});

module.exports = PT = mongoose.model('pt', pTSchema);
```

Insert New Record.

```
// Working as expected with validation
var newPT = new PT();
newPT.type = req.body.type;
newPT.save(function(err) {
   if (err)
      return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: JSON.stringify(err) })
   return req.res.status(200).send({status:true, data: newPT});
});
```

Update Records.

```
// While update single record it also executes schema validate and won't give permission to save.
// Please give me some suggestion on this.

PT.findOne({ _id : where }, function(err, responsePT) {
    if (!PT) {
        return res.status(500).send({ status: false, message: "ERROR" });
    }
    responsePT.type = req.body.type;
    responsePT.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: JSON.stringify(err) })
        return req.res.status(200).send({status:true, data: responsePT});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At, Final I didn't get any solution so, I update my code with `.pre('save',` It's fixed my problem.

I ignore updated entry.